# Visual Studio 19 not recognising SQL Server 2012 for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I want to run an ASP.NET project on VS 19 but whenever I open it, it shows an error dialog box that “this project requires SQL Server 2012 which is not installed on this computer” - but SQL Server 2012 is installed with all services running.

[image: Error message]

And database cannot be created showing an error

> A network related or instance specific error

I guess Visual Studio 19 is somehow not recognising SQL Server 2012 services and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Also tried to disable firewall and enable all TCP/UDP Connections but of no use, kindly help as it's very frustrating.

Comment: What do you mean "SQL 19" and "SQL 12"? There's no such thing.

Comment: I'm **assuming** that by "SQL 12" you **really** meant **SQL Server 2012** - you should be more **precise** with your questions and not be sloppy about naming things.....

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory. SQL Server 2012 is not the same as SQL Server 2019. Given Google doesn't return any results for this error message (aside from this very page) I'm guessing that this was an existing project that you're trying to open and that the error message is a pre-build or post-build step that a previous author added manually to the project.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2012 do you have installed? Note that the error mentions Express LocalDB - that feature *only* works with Express edition. So you may very well have 2012 installed but if it's e.g. Developer edition, that's not going to cut it. You can install both on the same machine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes Installing SQL Express LocalDB solved the issue as I had other SQL server tools installed but not SQL Express LocalDB, Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for using sloppy naming schemes as i'm new to Stack Overflow.

Installing *SQL Express LocalDB* helped me solve the problem, i thought i had it installed from the SQL Express tools available [Microsoft SQL Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads), but the *SQL Express LocalDB* was missing. It sounds stupid, but it is what it is, hope it helps anyone else.